# Row-mirror a table, ignoring null values

Tags: sas

I have

```
id | val1 | val2 | val3 | val4 | val5 | val6 | val7 | val8

1 | abc  | efg   | hij    | klm  | npo |  qrs  | tuv   | wxy

2 | hdi   | iijk   | klm   | null | null |  null | null | null 

3 | kkk  | iikl  | null | null |  null | null | null  | null

4 | klm  | null | null |  null | null | null | null  | null
```

I want

```
id | val1 | val2 | val3 | val4 | val5 | val6 | val7 | val8

1  | wxy  | tuv   | qrs   | npo  | klm |  hij  | efg   | abc

2 | klm   | iijk    | hdi  | null | null |  null | null | null

3 | iikl    | kkk   | null  | null | null  | null | null  | null

4 | klm  | | null  | null | null  | null | null  | null | null
```

My data can have any number of `val` columns. I need the last column value, if its not null, as the first column value in the want data set. Some `id`-rows can have data in all `val` columns, whereas others can have only few a `val` columns with data.

How can I transform my data?

Comment: If I understand this correctly, this is not a transpose, but rather a row-mirrored table, much like a `fliplr`, whilst ignoring all `null` values?

Comment: Are there ever missing values in between the non-missing values? Or are they always at the end of the line?  If they are in the middle do you want to preserve those?

Comment: Tom, there is no missing values in between.

Answer (score 1):

As long as all non-null values are aligned as in your example, the below code will mirror your table.

```
data want;
    input val1-val5;
    array v[*] val:;
    array tmp[5] _TEMPORARY_;

    /* Find the maximum variable in the array with a non-null value */
    do i = 1 to dim(v);
        if(v[i] = .) then leave;
    end;

    max = i-1;

    /* Save each variable into a temp array:
       value1 = value5
       value2 = value4 
       ... 
    */
    do i = 1 to max;
        tmp[i] = v[max-i+1];
    end;

    /* Swap values */
    do i = 1 to max;
        v[i] = tmp[i];
    end;    
 
    drop i max;

    datalines;
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 . .
9 10 . . .
;
run;
```

Output:

```
val1    val2    val3    val4    val5
5       4       3       2       1
8       7       6       .       .
10      9       .       .       .
```